# Genymotion, ошибка при создании виртуального устройства

Tags: android, genymotion

Когда выбираю любое устройство в Genymotion, при его создании выскакивает ошибка:

> Unable to create virtual device. Failed to create SD card

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Я перенес папки Genymotion из путей по умолчанию в созданные C:\VirtualBox. Как мне кажется система не смогла создать файл с SD превысив путь из 255 символов.
Сама машина развернулась теперь нормально. Пытаюсь запуститься :-)

Comment: Спасибо, Антон! Мне тоже Ваше решение помогло!

Comment: Спасибо большое, Антон, очень выручили!

Comment: Ставлю плюс за тех участников, которые сами не смогли. =)

Comment: Большое спасибо!!)) Помогло!!!